# RedBeanPHP ошибка: Uncaught [3D000] - SQLSTATE[3D000]: Invalid catalog name

Tags: php, mysql, framework, orm, redbeanphp

Вот ошибка :

> Uncaught [3D000] - SQLSTATE[3D000]: Invalid catalog name: 1046 No database selected trace: #0 Z:\home\localhost\www\lib\rb.php(881): RedBeanPHP\Driver\RPDO->runQuery('SELECT COUNT(*)...', Array)
>
>    #1 Z:\home\localhost\www\lib\rb.php(918): RedBeanPHP\Driver\RPDO->GetAll('SELECT COUNT(*)...', Array)
>    #2 Z:\home\localhost\www\lib\rb.php(3507): RedBeanPHP\Driver\RPDO->GetOne('SELECT COUNT(*)...', Array)
>
>    #3 Z:\home\localhost\www\lib\rb.php(5290): RedBeanPHP\Adapter\DBAdapter->getCell('SELECT COUNT(*)...', Array)
>    #4 Z:\home\localhost\www\lib\rb.php(7305): RedBeanPHP\QueryWriter\AQueryWriter->queryRecordCount('users', Array, 'login = ?', Array)
>    #5 Z:\home\localhost\www\lib\rb.php(8354): RedBeanPHP\Repository->count('users', 'login = ?', Array)
>    #6 Z:\home\localhost\www\lib\rb.php(11272): RedBeanPHP\OODB->count('users', 'login = ?', Array)
>    #7 Z:\home\localhost\www\save_user.php(69): RedBeanPHP\Facade::count('users', 'login = ?', Array)
>    #8 {main} thrown in Z:\home\localhost\www\lib\rb.php on line 719

Вот код :

```
require '/lib/rb.php';
R::setup('mysql:host=localhost;dbname = name','root','password');
$user = R::dispense('users');

    $user->login = $login;
    $user->password = $password;
    $user->gender = $gender;
    $user->forename = $forename;
    $id = R::store($user);

    $user = R::load('users' , $id );
    R::freeze(true);
```

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.

Answer (score 2):

У вас не выбрана база данных, вероятно проблема со строкой источника данных (DSN) в первом аргументе метода `setup`

```
R::setup('mysql:host=localhost;dbname = name','root','password');
```

Попробуйте убрать пробелы до и после имени базы данных `name`

```
R::setup('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=name','root','password');
```

Убедитесь, что ваша база данных действительно называется `name`, а не как-то иначе.

Answer (score 1):

Может кому пригодится

```
R::setup('mysql:=localhost;dbname=name','root','password');
```